Increment Sequence Reset to 1 Automatically in Postgres SQL
I have a table in a PostgresSQL where I am doing a migration from other database.
I have a id field which is defined by Auto increment using sequence feature in postgres.
Whenever I truncate the table and insert the records, It wont start from 1 instead, it starts last value before truncation.
How to handle it. Whenever I truncate the table, the sequence should start from 1.
Thanks,
Raja Pandi G R
A complete solution for an issue in PostgreSQL

Why do you want to start from 1 in the first place? This has no benefit while introducing the risk of creating accidental relations to records in other tables that used the old values.

@PanagiotisKanavos Truncate would fail if the fk used no action or restrict, get wiped, nullified or defaulted on cascade, set null or set default. Only the last one could potentially create a new link, but reassigning to a pre-configured default is hardly accidental. That being said, I agree the use case is somewhat unclear, and if they happen to use soft links, fk references undefined in DDL and unguarded by a proper constraint, with no regard for what happens on the other end - that's asking for trouble.

@Zegarek it won't if there's no FK constraint. You don't need to specify an FK constraint for a column to act as a foreign key. SQL (the language) mixes up the terms, and FOREIGN KEY actually defines a referential integrity constraint

@PanagiotisKanavos That's what I meant by "soft links, fk references undefined in DDL and unguarded by a proper constraint" and for those cases, I agreed you're making an important point.

You can tell TRUNCATE to handle this for you:
TRUNCATE my_table RESTART IDENTITY;


you can reset the sequence manually:
TRUNCATE TABLE your_table;
ALTER SEQUENCE your_table_id_seq RESTART WITH 1;
given your_table_id_seq is the name of the sequence associated with the id column in your table
